# What does "this" refer to in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, this, super

What does `this` refer to in the following code:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      bar: "baz",
    }
  }
}
```

I read YDKJS and, it says that `this` does not refer to the function itself, but isn't `this.state` in the code above setting the state of `Foo`?

Comment: it refers to the class (component) `Foo` here.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: `this` isn't different in react - it's just `this`

Comment: check this: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Maybe you should add `console.log(this)` to your constructor function

Comment: I mean I was hoping that someone would be able to explain it

Answer (score 0):

With classes you are building a blueprint to eventually create specific instances. `constructor` contains the code that is being run when a new instance is being created. So `this` inside a class always (except for [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)) refers to the specific instance that is created.

For example:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width, name) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.name = name
  }

  calcArea() {
    console.log(this.name)
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

const square1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 'square1');
const square2 = new Rectangle(15, 15, 'square2');

console.log(square1.calcArea()) // square1 100
console.log(square2.calcArea()) // square2 225
```

As you can see, `this` refers not just to a generic `Rectangle` but always to the particular instance you are using. The same goes for React Components.

So to answer your question

```
this.state = {
    bar: "baz",
}
```

is not setting the state of `Foo`. But it's setting the state of the particular instance that gets created with the **blueprint** (the class) `Foo`. Because at some point in React's code, it calls `new Foo`. And only there it will set the state of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is the keyword, which holds reference to something, in this case, this is used within a class naming Foo, so when we use the keyword "this" inside the class it refers to class itself.

By meaning it reference to Foo, means now you can access the other properties and function belonging to class with help of this keyword. Class is like a blueprint, does not exist on its own, we create objects/instances of classes to access them. Once the object/instance is made, and we want to access the properties of class among themselves we use this keyword.

In react object creation is done by below syntax

```
<Foo />
```

That when the component is being called. Now in constructor by using the code

```
this.state = {
      bar: "baz",
    }
```

we are making sure that we can access bar key across this component from any other function as well. something like below

```
render(){
    console.log(this.state.bar);
    return (<div>{this.state.bar}</div>)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to vote or comment, so I will add my comment here.

@vellip answer is mostly correct, however, the sentence "So this inside a class always (except for static methods) refers to the specific instance that is created." is not totally precise, because in javascript "this" is dependent on the execution context, and not only lexical scope, i.e. being "inside a class". So if a class does event handling for instance, "this" might just as well be a reference to the element that created the event.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you provided, `Foo` is just the description (or blueprint) for some view, it is not the actual view or instance of the blueprint. React creates the instance of `Foo` when it has to render it as actual view and it does so whenever it encounters `<Foo />` inside your jsx. React internally uses `React.createElement` method to create instances of its components, so to create an instance of `Foo` it will do something like this internally:

`const fooInstance = React.createElement(Foo)`

`fooInstance` is a plain javascript object if you log it and it is referred by `this` inside `Foo`. I hope now you understand that `this` inside `Foo` doesn't referes to `Foo`, rather it refers to instances of `Foo` which react creates using `React.createElement()` whenever it encounters ` in you jsx.